# what are the dependent and independent variables

Tags: likert, dependent-variable

I am measuring Covid anxiety using likert scale, according to people age, gender, pcr result, and educational level.

Which variable can I consider to be dependent and which independent?

Comment: Are you trying to predict COVID anxiety based on age, gender, PCR result, and education level?

Answer (score 0):

if covariance is ~0, they are independent. if it isn't, they are dependent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

Comment: This is incorrect and does not answer the question.

Comment: agree to disagree I guess